# How to let Isabelle "compute" THE output of an inductive predicate

Tags: isabelle

I have an inductive predicate `P` that behaves like a partial function. In other words, `P x y = P x y' ⟹ y = y'`. I'd like to let Isabelle "compute" THE output of the predicate when proving theorems on a concrete value (for an example).

For example, let's say that we have the following predicate `div2`.

```
inductive div2 :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
  Zero: "div2 0 0" |
  SS: "div2 n m ⟹ div2 (Suc (Suc n)) (Suc m)"
code_pred[show_modes] div2 .
```

How can I prove the following lemma without providing the output `m` (the term is too big to type in the actual case)?

```
lemma "(THE m. div2 8 m) ≠ 5"
  sorry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties on `the` and `some` work nearly always the same way (and sledgehammer does not work well on them).

1. Prove existence of a witness ;
2. For the only: prove uniqueness of the witness ;
3. Deduce with `theI` or `someI` that the property holds on the value ;
4. Prove the theorem you actually wanted to prove.

In your case that translates to proving that 5 is not a witness:

```
inductive_cases div2E: ‹div2 m n›

lemma "(THE m. div2 8 m) ≠ 5"
proof -
  have ex_div2: ‹div2 8 4› (*1: witness*)
    by (auto simp: numeral_eq_Suc div2.intros)
  moreover have ‹div2 8 m ⟹ m = 4› for m (*2: uniqueness*)
    by (force simp: numeral_eq_Suc elim: div2E)
  ultimately have ‹div2 8 (THE x. div2 8 x)› (*3: property holds*)
    by (rule theI)
  (*4 use the property*)
  then show ?thesis
    by (force simp: numeral_eq_Suc elim: div2E)

qed
```

If you don't need `the`, use `some` instead, that avoids the very annoying uniqueness proof each time.

For your use case, I would advise to write the theorem as `div2 8 m ⟹ m ≠ 5`, which is equivalent, but much easier to use and to prove.

```
lemma "div2 8 m ⟹ m ≠ 5"
  by (force simp: numeral_eq_Suc elim: div2E)
```

For reusability:

- Factor step 3 in a separate lemma (if there is a meaningful way to express when an invert exists)
- Hide as much as possible `the` predicates by introducing definitions and avoid referring to the lambda-definition as much as possible.